# How to make angular2 custom validators to run after we get the value

Tags: angular2-forms

If I pass hard coded values in offerCheck validator it is working fine. But if I get values from api, null values is getting passed in paramets. Form is getting executed before we get the values from service. Please help me to make validate check after getting values from api.

```js
this.newOffer = "aaa";
this.oldOffer = "aaa";

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = fb.group({
      'offer': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.offerCheck(newOfer, oldOffer)])],
    })

    offerCheck(new, old) {
      return (control: FormControl) => {
        if (new == old) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get values from api?

Comment: I am  subscribing values onInit function. offercheck validator is gettign executed before i pass  subscribed values, ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceSubscription = this.offerService.getOffers.subscribe(
      result => { 
         this.newOffer = result.new;
      }
    );
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is probably the `AsyncValidatorFn`, here's a very simple example of how to create one:

```
export const OfferCheck: AsyncValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): Observable<boolean> => {

 if (new == old) {
   return Observable.of(this.http.get('/some-endpoint').first().map(res => res.data));
 }
};
```

You don't provide enough information so this is just a guess on how you'd want it to be. But it should point you in the right decision.

An alternative method would be to use `setValidators` of the control(s) after you've fetched the data:

```
this.formGroup.get('offer').setValidators([Validators.required, this.offerCheck(newOfer, oldOffer)]);
```

I hope this helps.